# Reactjs - background image of a div is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a background image of a div in a component but it's not working.

```
{slides.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.id} className="item_slider"
                         style={{background: `url(/images/covers/${item.cover})`}}
                    >
                        <div className="caption">
                            <h4>{item.topic}</h4>
                            <p>{item.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
```

item_slider css

```
.item_slider {
    height: 700px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

images are in public folder though I copied them in src folder also but no luck. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try backgroundImage instead of background, react style properties are camel case :)

Comment: Tried both but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`/images/covers/${item.cover}`) + ')'}}
```

If it doesn't work, try with an image URL:

```
const url = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/f2c/effi-1-1366221.jpg";
```

and:

```
style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`url`) + ')'}}
```

Does this work? If it does, the problem is probably with the image path.
Put the image in the same folder of the component and then try (I assume that the image name is zzz.jpg:

```
style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`./zzz.jpg}`) + ')'}}
```

If this works as well, check again the path...

Comment: Tried it also. It's showing module not found. can't resolve '/images/covers'

Answer (score 0):

Try with your own URL

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._size = '350x150'
    this._style = {
      backgroundImage: `url(http://via.placeholder.com/${this._size})`
    }
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div style={this._style} className="example">
        <h1>Content here</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.example {
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So, your style should work, except with `backgroundImage`:

```
...
style={{backgroundImage: `url(/images/covers/${item.cover})`}}
...
```

Just make sure your paths are correct and `${item.cover}` actually has a value. If it still doesn't work, might as well try and move that style from CSS into your inline style because it's the same element anyway.

Comment: I suspect there's a problem with either your data or pathing. Try using a full URL including the `http`. Or, you can try to not use the template literal and do it the classic way: `url('/images/covers/' + item.cover)`. By the way, is your project generated by `create-react-app`?